# OpenCV mat* image = (Mat*) image

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I'm new to OpenCV and C++. I was looking to use the setMouseCallback function and did it as so:

```
setMouseCallback("Window Name", functionName, &frame);

void functionName("int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* param"){
Mat *image = (Mat*)param;
//other stuff here
}
```

I would just like to ask...Why do I have to put (Mat*)param and not just put Mat *param.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you have in this example is an explicit type conversion (see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). `param` is of a different type than your `Mat* image` and thus you cannot simply assign the pointer `param`, which in all likelihood has a different type than `Mat*` (see juanchopanza's question) to `image`. So you have to tell the compiler that even if the pointer type is different, the underlying object type is compatible with being assigned to a `Mat *`.

The other thing you are mentioning: `Mat *param` has a completely different meaning, it would mean that you are creating a new `Mat` pointer with name `param`.

Comment: P.S. while the classes you are working with are OpenCV classes, which can be of interest for the type conversion, your actual question  `(T*) param` vs `T *param` is a very generic c/c++ questions and not OpenCV specific